# IOS slide menu like facebook and path 2.0 that works with storyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa

I try looking everywhere for opensource but couldn't find a cocoa control that has the following combination.

1. Slide Menu
2. Story Board.
3. Navigation controller.
4. TabBar controller.

I found one open source control that works with 1,2,3 but doesn't work with uitabbarcontroller.
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/saslidemenu

Comment: Here is just an example of how to use the IIViewDeckController with storyboards that helped me out. https://github.com/simonrice/ViewDeckStoryboardExample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used [IIViewDeckController](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/iiviewdeckcontroller) in a project that involved all of the things that you list.

Comment: it doesn't wire up with control drag like a tab bar controller or something would. you have to configure the IIViewDeckController in code. But there's no reason you can't use it in a storyboard project.

Comment: Is it possible to disbale side menu for all view-controller other than your home view?

Answer (score 4):

I made a video (3 parts) on youtube on how to make a sliding menu like the on you are looking for. I show you how to set up the project and get everything linked up.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJJMyzdB9uI

The way this is set up, you should be able to just select UINavigationController instead of UIViewController when creating your files from the first video.

I use ECSlidingViewController because its the easiest to customize.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have you been able to use it in portrait mode? Whenever I switch to portrait mode it resizes the main view and it no longer fits the screen.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple one I wrote. It's built on top of UINavigationController so you can use all UINavigationcontroller functions as well as slide function. No need to inherit any base class for your ViewControllers like other libraries require. Works both on Storyboard and in code.

I haven't tried, but I'm pretty sure if you set a tab-bar-controller as the root view controller of this custom navigation controller it should work as expected.

https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu

Comment: do you have slide menu demo with expandable tableview ? if do you have then send me that demo link. thanks in advanced.

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya Those are two completely different things. https://github.com/aryaxt/UITableView-Expand-Sample

Comment: your code is not working well in ipad. how can i set in ipad also

Comment: pls give me fast reply. i was already implemeted in iphone. in ipad not working well. pls help me

Comment: Pls help me for supporting in ipad. in your demo also not working well in ipad. thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/arturdev/AMSlideMenu 
You can use this simple library. 
Just connect your menu (tableViewController) to your tabBarController with a custom segue of type AMSlideMenuContentSegue.